# How do i find the ratio between from centre to edge and centre to a corner of a hexagon

Tags: trigonometry

I have a hexagon which i divided into triangles like this:

[image]

If i know the length of a line from the centre to an edge, how can i find the scalar to multiply the length to become equal to the length of the red line going from the center to the vertex:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle between the red line and the blue line in $30^\circ$. Then the ratio of the blue length to red length is $\cos 30^\circ$. So $$red=\frac{blue}{\cos 30^\circ}\approx 1.15\ blue$$

Answer (score 2):

The red line is half of the longest diagonal of a regular hexagon, which is equal in length to its side. The length of blue line from the center to the side is the height of one of the six equilateral triangles comprising the hexagon and is equal to $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$ where are is the side length. Thus the ratio in question is $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$